# What is TypeScript's ThisType used for?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript comes with an interface [`ThisType`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/76401adba33b71e70d76961d7d66064243be0243/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1629-L1632). I couldn't find much documentation on it, so I'm wondering: what is it used for? How do I use it? How does it work?

Comment: It's documented: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypet

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ThisType` is documented here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypet (thanks to [@axiac for linking that in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029032/what-is-typescripts-thistype-used-for#comment96810875_55029032))

However, the example the docs use feels a bit convoluted to me. This is the easiest way I've found to think about it:

If you add `& ThisType<T>` to the type of an object, the functions within that object will have `T` as the type used for `this`, where `T` can be whatever type you define. This is helpful if you can't otherwise specify what `this` should be through the normal TypeScript mechanisms (it's not a `class`, etc.)

If we imagine a world where we're writing some code that registers some helper functions, you could write it like this:

```
interface HelperThisValue {
    logError: (error: string) => void;
}

let helperFunctions: { [name: string]: Function } & ThisType<HelperThisValue> = {
    hello: function() {
        this.logError("Error: Something went wrong!"); // TypeScript successfully recognizes that "logError" is a part of "this".
        this.update(); // TS2339: Property 'update' does not exist on HelperThisValue.
    }
}

registerHelpers(helperFunctions);
```

As I've indicated in the comments above, TypeScript now knows the correct type, and will give errors if we misuse it.

Note that like all of TypeScript's typings, using `ThisType` has no effect on the resulting JavaScript code. There must be code elsewhere that ensures that when the members of `helperFunctions` get called, the proper `this` value is set (e.g. through use of `Function.bind`, `Function.apply`, `Function.call`, etc.)

Comment: seems can't use ThisType in Function? Like this: 

let helperFunction: Function & ThisType<HelperThisValue> = function() {
    this.logError('Error: Something went wrong!');
}
;

Comment: @chickenDinner That's correct. ThisType is specifically for use with objects. However, you can specify 'this' as the first parameter, like so:

const helperFunction: (this: HelperThisValue) => any = function() { this.logError('Error: Something went wrong!'); };

Note that the function assigned can't be an arrow function, as those receive their 'this' value from the surrounding scope, so specifying 'this' wouldn't make sense.