# Typescript this infered type unable to get the type of parent super class

Tags: typescript

I have a child class that inherit from a parent class. The child class this is unable to get the typing of the parent class

```ts
class Foo {
  foo: string = ''
  merge(opts: Partial<this>): this { return this }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  bar() {
    return this.merge({ // typing error because foo is not declared as a property of Bar
      foo: '3'
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 2 options:

1. The first would be to override the method in the inheriting classes

```
class Foo {
  foo: string = ''
  merge(opts: Partial<Foo>): Partial<Foo> { return this }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  asd: string = 'qweqwe';

  merge(opts: Partial<Bar>): Partial<Bar> { return super.merge(opts); }

  bar() {
    return this.merge({
      foo: '3',
      asd: "ceva"
    })
  }
}

let a = new Foo()
console.log(a.merge({}))

let b = new Bar()
console.log(b.bar())
```

2. Second would be to create a generic `merge` method that will need to be passed a type at the call site. Something similar to this.

```
class Foo {
  foo: string = ''
  merge<U extends Foo>(opts: Partial<U>): Partial<U> { return this as unknown as Partial<U> }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  asd: string = 'qweqwe';

  bar() {
    return this.merge<Bar>({
      foo: '3',
      asd: "ceva"
    })
  }
}

let a = new Bar()
console.log(a.bar())
```

Comment: I have come up with the solution 2 myself as well; but I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve that. That's what prompted the question. From what I can see it is the best way. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `this` as a type in this case. Replace it with the utility `ThisType`.

```
class Foo {
  foo: string = ''
  merge(opts: Partial<ThisType<Foo>>): ThisType<Foo> { return this }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNEC5oQBcAnASwDsBzaAXmgHI71oBbAUyItYAp4AHAiHgAKYIgRJgQAHgAqACxIQZAT16spCeAD4tASjzzFKtRsRaU0IqwIBXImWgEFMAL6o3qUJBgAhUdFYADwJWMgATGE0UJgAjUS5daIwMK1t7R2cAOjYObmRoAHoCx1VyKnYieCJoGNZgMBsIVixEaEVoMngCaDC68Csw6Egh6F5KtTFlaHhMaD8iJmSW%20Dw6AGZGJZddJjcXIA)

Comment: But I don't want to restrict the returned type only to `<Foo>`; I want it to be all the properties available on the child class

Comment: Hmm, that is kind of a problem. The code inside the superclass does not know about its descendants. But you can manually specifiy all possible return types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weXvgW).

Comment: @TobiasS. That's not a good example, as the base class knows about descendants now.

Comment: Yes exactly @RaduDiță; in my case the base class does not know where it gonna be extended

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYkOzN) ? You will lose any kind of type safety inside the `merge` function, afterall how should it now what subclasses might extend it...

Comment: This is not what `ThisType` if for. Here you just use `Foo`. `ThisType` is a special assertion used to override the type of `this` when it cannot be determined from context. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029032/what-is-typescripts-thistype-used-for

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass the child class as a generic argument to the base class:

```
class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
  foo: string = ''
  merge(opts: Partial<T>): Partial<Foo<T>> { return this }
}

class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
  x: string = ''
  bar() {
    return this.merge({
      foo: '3',
      x: 'a'
    })
  }
}
```